# PayuMoney Netbanking option is not appearing when integrating the java kit

Tags: payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayuMoney for netbanking and the option does not appear in the TEST environment only debit card and credit card option are displayed and the transaction is successful for credit card.How do I include the netbanking option?Is it not available in the TEST environment?Please suggest.When I run the sample code it gets redirected to option of netbanking.How redirecting to the same URL is not giving me that option?

Answer (score 0):

Banks and Wallets started showing up for me once i changed the status to production.